# Android MapView API v2 not rendering, tried it all

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

It feels like I have tried every tutorial available online .. 
I just cannot get my MapView to render using Google Maps API v2 for Android.

I have thoroughly followed the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key) but still, no luck.

The MapView buttons appear as they normally do, and the "My location" button aswell. But the actual map is not rendered. If I use the development keystore to generate the API-key then it works. Not with the production keystore though..

1. I have enabled the Google Maps Api v2 [here](https://console.developers.google.com/project).
2. I have generated the SHA1 fingerprint of my production keystore.
3. I have entered the SHA1 fingerprint along with my application's package name(which i double checked) in the correct section from step 1.
4. Ive added this ...

   ```
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="my_key" /> <!-- I changed this one -->
   ```

Within the `<application>` element of my applications manifest.

5.Ive enabled glES and added the correct permissions. This is my list of permissions

```
 <permission
    android:name="se.appshack.frittfram.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="se.appshack.frittfram.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Now when I try to render a `SupportMapFragment` No map is displayed.

[Here is my logcat](https://gist.github.com/sibe7691/76726626cb59c156f2d7)

As I said. It works using the debug keystore but not the production keystore.

What might I be missing out?

FYI I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Have you changed the API_KEY to the one generated from production keystore?

Comment: Yes I did, just chose not post it here, ill edit thanks

Comment: ok,i wanted to check you have two different map API_KEYS for production keystore and debug keystore, and changed the API_KEY in manifest accordingly while generating the apk with production keystore.